# SQL Server : submit leave application

Tags: sql-server

I have just started learning SQL and I'm really struggling. I have a very simple `employees` table and trying to link it with a `leave` table.

```
CREATE TABLE [MOUNTAIN].[VOLUNTEER]
(
    [EMPLOYEE_ID] [int] identity (1,1) not null,
    [NAME] [nvarchar] (20) not null, 
    [PHONENUMBER] [nvarchar] (20) not null,
    [ADDRESS] [NVARCHAR] (200) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TBALE [EMPLOYEE_LEAVE]
(
    [LEAVE_ID] [int] identity (1,1) not null,
    [EMPLOYEE_ID] [int] not null,
    [START_DATE] [DATE]  not null,
    [END_DATE] [DATE]  not null,
);
```

I want these to be linked so an employee can enter start date and end date and submit it online and it will update in SQL Server.

I'm sure this is very simple and i have been searching for hours trying to find a solution.

Comment: What is your question?  Sample data and desired results help describe a question.  A generic "how do I build an application" isn't appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Simple join : Select  * From VOLUNTEER V INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE_LEAVE EL ON V.EMPLOYEE_ID = V.EMPLOYEE_ID WHERE  getdate() BETWEEN START_DATE AND END_DATE

Comment: I think you need to give a bit more detail on the exact problem that you're facing. The actual definitions of the tables look fine